# Create a keyboard shortcut for macOS Share Menu

Tags: macos, menu-bar

UPDATE: Added screenshots to clarify what the macOS share menu is. This is located on iOS and macOS as an arrow icon on Apple applications (a majority of them). The screenshots are from Safari's share menu.

I'm looking for a way to toggle the Share Menu you can find on many apps such as Mail, Safari, Messages, Finder, etc.

I've looked everywhere for a way to create a shortcut for a specific option on the dropdown. Such as the Message share menu or Reminders. The dropdown application option I want is not an apple native application.

This [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4195759) is exactly what I'm looking for however their resolution was to not create a successfully working shortcut for the Share Menu.

Any help would be appreciated. Per usual, searching anything macOS related gives apple.support results that don't have anything to do with you search keywords therefore that was no help.

[image: Share menu in the Safari toolbar]

[image: Share menu from the File menu dropdown ***Notice the key-bind for your default Mail application]

Comment: In High Sierra, there is already a shortcut for Share via Email (Cmd+I for Safari for instance).

Comment: The share menu option I want to shortcut isn't Mail.

Comment: What is the share menu? Screen shot or key combination?

Comment: @bmike want to elaborate on what you mean? The share menu is a build-in iOS and MacOS app feature to send what’s in the current application to another application. I don’t know what you’re asking so I hope that helps.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the custom shortcuts via System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts

The trick is to specify the exact path to the menu item. For instance if you wish to add a shortcut for Share Messages, you have to write for "Menu Title":

```
File->Share->Messages
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey there, It isn't working for me, or I'm not doing it correctly. Would you be able to screenshot the shortcut?

Comment: I've added screenshots to the answer.

Comment: IT WORKS! YES! Thank you! I've been trying to figure out how to do that for a year or two!

Comment: Perfect. I've been looking for a way to quickly share a page in Safari to Notes. "File->Share->Notes" worked. I used Command-Shift-N (similar to "Email this Page" default of Command-Shift-I).

In Safari this automatically removed that shortcut from its previous use (New Private Window) but not in Chrome.