# Remap quit app keyboard shortcut globally

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

In Windows and Linux I can remap the Quit Application key globally to something else (usually `Ctrl + F4`). Mac has the ability to remap keys based on a [menu item name](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321044/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-macos-share-menu). However, this does not work for Quit Application since it has a different name for each app. Specifically, it follows the pattern: `[App Name] > Quit [App Name]`. To use this method, I would need to remap every app independently.

Comment: Answered here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321044/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-macos-share-menu

Comment: @Jahhein This does not work for quitting an app since it relies on the menu item name. Unfortunately, quitting an app is named differently depending on the app. Generally called [App Name] > Quit [App Name]

Comment: There are several Q&A linked at the top of your question, some of the answers recommend Karabiner Elements. This (or Ukelele) is the way to go if you want to refine/remap keys on OS level.

Answer (score 1):

You can remap your keyboard, for me it was really exhausting to search a guide to do this, but I can share a few tips to do it with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/).

First of all, this is a powerful tool to remap every key and modifier (like caps, option, command, shift...) from your keyboard, but I think you might be overwhelmed with all the possible settings and documentation, so I here's my advice:

1. Search for the most useful keyboard layout in the default settings in your mac, in my case it was Spanish.
2. With Ukelele, create **new from current input source** and only remap what is needed. In my case, it was only needed to add backslash () with the combination of [Option + Shift + 7].
3. And finally follow the instructions to install in your system.

This answer is related to this [post](https://suragch.medium.com/how-to-make-a-custom-keyboard-for-mac-os-c9f607428372) which shows how to create from scratch a keyboard layout.

Comment: I don't want to create a new keyboarding layout. I just want to remap the Quit App to a different key combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can remap all menu shortcuts in the keyboard shortcuts section called “All Apps”.

[Remap menu item shortcuts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321044/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-macos-share-menu)

Comment: This does not work since it relies on the menu item name. Unfortunately, quitting an app is named differently depending on the app. Generally called [App Name] > Quit [App Name]