# Create share files from Finder shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

When I want to share file with email or iMessage in Finder, I have to right click on that file, choose share option, and choose email or iMessage. I want to create keyboard shortcut for this. e.g. I choose files, use command+shift+E or I, and it opens email or iMessage share windows. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Does this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321044/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-macos-share-menu

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create a simple shortcut from a contextual right-click menu. It might need some deeper approach, perhaps to generate a Service.